# How can I copy AzureAD user groups with PowerShell for matching accounts?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm not super advanced with `PowerShell`, but this is my most complicated script I've had to write.

I'm new to a company and we're migrating a subsidiary from accounts with the main company's domain name to accounts with the subsidiary's domain name. For example, a John Smith would have both a `jsmith@maincompany.com` account and a `john.smith@subsidiary.com` account.

Naturally, those accounts are in different O365 groups. What I want to do is:

- Get all of the accounts from the subsidiary domain so I know who I'm copying to
- Get the matching accounts for their main company domains so I know where I'm copying from
- Get all of the groups from each of those main company accounts
- Copy that group membership for each of those respective accounts

I'm thinking of a series of `foreach` loops is the best way to do it, but my primary concern is I don't want to copy everyone's groups to everyone else.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$subsidiaryEmails = Get-AzureADUser -all $true | where { $_.UserPrincipalName.EndsWith("subsidiary.com") }

$mainEmails = foreach ($subsidiaryEmail in $subsidiaryEmails) {Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $subsidiaryEmail.DisplayName | where-object {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@maincompany.com"}}

$mainGroupMembership = foreach ($mainEmail in $mainEmails) {Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $mainEmail.objectId}

foreach ($group in $mainGroupMembership) {Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $subsidiaryEmail.ObjectId}
```

It's super ugly and probably won't work, but I feel like I've got the right pieces together but don't know how to fit the puzzle together.

I feel like a nested `foreach` is the best option, but I don't know enough about them to feel confident in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you think that using multiple nested foreach is super ugly.

First of all, ideally the logic should be like this:

```
$subsidiaryEmails = Get-AzureADUser -all $true | where { $_.UserPrincipalName.EndsWith("subsidiary.com") }

foreach ($subsidiaryEmail in $subsidiaryEmails) 
{
    $mainEmails = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $subsidiaryEmail.DisplayName | where-object {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@maincompany.com"}

    foreach ($mainEmail in $mainEmails) 
    {
        $mainGroupMembership = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $mainEmail.objectId
        
        foreach ($group in $mainGroupMembership) 
        {
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $subsidiaryEmail.ObjectId
        }
    }
}
```

We can avoid some foreach like this:

```
$subsidiaryEmails = Get-AzureADUser -all $true | where { $_.UserPrincipalName.EndsWith("subsidiary.com") }

foreach ($subsidiaryEmail in $subsidiaryEmails) 
{
    Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $subsidiaryEmail.DisplayName | where-object {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "*@maincompany.com"} | Get-AzureADUserMembership | select-object -property @{N='RefObjectId';E={$subsidiaryEmail.ObjectId }},@{N='ObjectId';E={$_.ObjectId }} | Add-AzureADGroupMember
}
```

This script does not consider whether you have multiple (more than two) accounts with the same **DisplayName** and whether your subdomain accounts may already exist in the target group. Please modify it according to your actual situation.